# Using Javascript to write a function which compares two trees and returns true if they are equal in structure and in value and false if there are not

Tags: javascript

Given the following class:

```
class TreeNode {
  constructor(data, left=null, right=null) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }
}
```

complete the function

```
const binaryTreeCompare = (a, b) => {};
```

which compares the two trees defined by TreeNodes a and b and returns true if they are equal in structure and in value and false otherwise.

Sample Tests

```
let assert = require('chai').assert;
  var aNode = {val: 1, left: null, right: null};
  var bNode = {val: 1, left: null, right: null};
  var cNode = {val: 2, left: null, right: null};
describe("example test", () => {
    it("Should return true for equal nodes", () => {
        assert.equal(compare(aNode, bNode), true);
    });
    it("Should return false for non-equal nodes", () => {
        assert.equal(compare(aNode, cNode), false);
    });
});
```

What I have done so far

```
function compare(a, b){
if (a==null && b==null) 
  return(true);
    else if (a!=null && b!=null) {
    return(
      a->data == b->data &&
      binaryTreeCompare(a->left, b->left) &&
      binaryTreeCompare(a->right, b->right)
    );
  }
    else return(false);
}
```

Its giving me an error

I expect the output to be true if TreeNodes a and b are equal in structure and in value and false otherwise.

Comment: Any example input and expected output?

Comment: Your current syntax is invalid, what are you trying to do with the lines like `a->data == b->data &&`?

Comment: whats the correct syntax

Comment: @smovmoth the correct JavaScript syntax should be `a.data` and `b.data`. The syntax `a->data` and `b->data` looks like a PHP syntax to me.

Comment: ok already noted

Answer (score 1):

It think its just like comparing two objects. You can create your own function which compare two nested objects using recursion.

```js
var a = {val: 1, left: null, right: null};
  var b = {val: 1, left: null, right: null};
  var c = {val: 2, left: null, right: null};

function compObj(a,b){
  if(typeof b !== "object" && b !== null) return false;
  console.log(a,b)
  if(Object.keys(a).length === Object.keys(b).length){
    for(let key in a){
      if(typeof a[key] === "object" && a[key] !== null){
        let temp = compObj(a[key],b[key]);
        if(!temp) return false;
      }
      if(a[key] !== b[key]) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(compObj(a,b))
```

Comment: Should return true for equal nodes, should return false for not equal nodes

Comment: @smovmoth I know that.. For which particular input its returning wrong result